# Translate "Order total"

Tags: i18n-l10n, commerce

I have translated my site into Japanese using all the required modules and po files.

But now I'm not able to translate the text "Order total" which appears in Checkout process.

[image]

I tried applying patches as suggested [here](https://www.drupal.org/node/1121722) but it didn't help me. Please tell me how to change this text.

Comment: Have you applied the patch on [this comment](https://www.drupal.org/node/1121722#comment-5700282)?

Comment: Yes, I tried that one as well. But it didn't help me.

Comment: Have you cleared caches?

Comment: Yes, I tried clearing the caches as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This post](https://drupalcommerce.org/comment/5828#comment-5828) discusses the very same issue. Also, as mentioned in [this comment](http://drupal.org/node/1451132#comment-5984944),

> 1) You have to go to this page admin/config/regional/i18n/strings And
>   set the language to english..than the translation strings can be made
>   to your language.
>
> 2) You need to go to admin/config/regional/translate/i18n_string and
>   enable
>
> Select text groups  Fields 3) Then the fields are between the normal
>   translation page to be able to translate:
>   admin/config/regional/translate/translate
>
> 4) After adding translation and nothing showing, back to
>   admin/config/regional/translate/i18n_string Enable Fields and click
>   REFRESH.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Ok. Will give it a try.

Comment: Nice to know that. Cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

```
function template_preprocess_field(&$variables, $hook) {

  if ($variables['field_name_css'] == 'commerce-order-total') {
    $variables['items'][0]['#markup'] = str_replace('Order total', t('Order total'), $variables['items'][0]['#markup']);
  }

}
```